# Average values from multiple rows if a portion of associated ID matches

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a groundwater model output file that contains modeled water levels for approximately 200 wells. The tricky part is that the wells can have up to 5 values depending on the number of model layers (various depths) that the well spans. These values need to be averaged so that they can then be compared to a single observed water level in another data frame. Each well has an 11 character ID (i.e. HARN0000219). If a well has 4 layers, the model ID gets adjusted for each additional layer after the first (I have no control over how the model output file is created). For example, a well with 4 layers would have 4 values and the associated ID's would be: HARN0000219, HARN0000219.1, HARN0000219.2, HARN0000219.3.

How would I calculate average water level by base well ID?

Example data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'wl': [4568.35, 4538.85, 4156.48, 4156.54, 4156.59, 4156.61],
    'ID': ['GRAN0000800', 'HARN0000009', 'HARN0000219', 'HARN0000219.1', 'HARN0000219.2', 'HARN0000219.3']
})
```

I'm assuming it would start with something like this, but have no idea where to go from here.

```
for well, row in well_mod.iterrows():
    if # first 11 characters = next:
        # average all wl values
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new series containing the relevant prefix of `"ID"` and group by that series. For example,

```
# take first 11 characters of ID
key = df['ID'].str[:11]

# average water level for each base ID
df.groupby(key)['wl'].mean()
```

```
ID
GRAN0000800    4568.350
HARN0000009    4538.850
HARN0000219    4156.555
Name: wl, dtype: float64
```

Depending on how your IDs are structured, the following may be more appropriate.

```
# take everything from ID before the period
key = df['ID'].str.split('.').str[0]
```

Comment: Everything always seems so easy after the fact. Thanks for your input on this @Igor! I had actually already created another column in the original df using the .str.split(','). str[0], I just didn't know about the groupby function, let alone combining it with .mean(). Works perfectly!

Comment: Great! As a rule of thumb, if you find yourself looping over Pandas objects in Python, consider that there is probably a solution using Pandas functions/methods which is faster.